Angular 17: Resizer using Cdk Drag
I am trying to rewrite a resizer using cdk drag. The way I have taken seems valid, but there is little control during resizing, the size seems to follow an exponential trend.
Surely I am missing something, I am looking for help.
All with signals in mind and relative refresh of the component when asynchronous updates arrive
Stackblitz project


Problem is now solved, stackblitz project is updated for those who need it
